# Understanding proof that if $c_1 d_1(x,y) \leq d_2 (x,y) \leq c_2 d_1 (x,y)$ then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Theorem.** If there are strictly positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that
>
> $$c_1 d_1(x,y) \leq d_2 (x,y) \leq c_2 d_1 (x,y)$$
>
> for all $x,y \in X$, then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent metrics on $X$.
>
> **Proof.** (for one direction) Let $U$ be open in $(X, d_1)$. Then for $a \in X$ there > exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that
>
> $$\{x \in X; d_1(x,a) < \epsilon\} \subset U.$$
>
> But then
>
> $$\{x \in X; d_2(x,a) < c_1\epsilon\} \subset \{x \in X; d_1(x,a) < \epsilon\} \subset U$$
>
> and $U$ is open in $(X, d_2)$.

The line I don't understand is the one that says $\{x \in X; d_2(x,a) < c_1\epsilon\} \subset \{x \in X; d_1(x,a) < \epsilon\}$. Why is the former a subset of the latter? I don't see the justification of this.

Comment: Hint: the inequality $c_1d_1(x,y)\le d_2(x,y)$ can be written $d_1(x,y)\le\frac{1}{c_1}d_2(x,y)$, and then apply $d_2(x,y)<c_1\epsilon$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Topologically-equivalent/metrically-equivalent metrics and the same topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617677/topologically-equivalent-metrically-equivalent-metrics-and-the-same-topology)

Comment: Strange that the question has been upvoted so many times This question has been answered many many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $c_{1}d_{1}(x,y) \leq d_{2}(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

For membership in $\{x \in X: d_{2}(x,a) < c_{1} \epsilon \}$, we have that $d_{2}(x,a) < c_{1} \epsilon$.

Therefore, we conclude that $c_{1}d_{1}(x,a) \leq d_{2}(x,a) < c_{1} \epsilon$, thus $c_{1}d_{1}(x,a) < c_{1} \epsilon$, and thus we can say $d_{1}(x,a) < \epsilon$ since $c_{1}$ is positive.

Comment: I can figure out why $d_1(x,a) < \epsilon$, but I don't see how $d_2(x,a) < c_1\epsilon$ is $< d_1(x,a) < \epsilon$, since it's supposed to be a subset

Comment: If you can conclude that $d_{1}(x,a) < \epsilon$ from $d_{2}(x,a) < c_{1} \epsilon$, then you are done. You are showing that the restriction on the first set guarantees the restriction on the second, so the former must be a subset.